# Batch file: Two consecutive IFs

Tags: windows, if-statement, batch-file, cmd, errorlevel

I'm trying to understand the syntax of IF in batch files.

Given this code (works):

```
CHOICE /C YN /M "Do it?"
IF ERRORLEVEL == 2 GOTO skip
IF ERRORLEVEL == 1 GOTO doIt
GOTO end

:doIt
echo Do it!
GOTO end

:skip
echo Abort!
GOTO end

:end
```

Why can't I change the order of the two IF's? If I would write `IF ERRORLEVEL == 1 GOTO doIt` at first, I get wrong behavior. Now `Do it` gets executed every time, regardless of the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`if` command](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) supports a few special (case-insensitive) keywords:

- `exist` (to check for file existence)
- `defined` (to check for environment variable)
- `ErrorLevel` (to check for the last error)
- `CmdExtVersion` (to check for command extensions)

If any of those is encountered immediately behind `if`, `if /I`, `if not` or `if /I not`, special comparison modes are entered. If none of these keywords is present, a normal comparison of two values is expected (using the comparison operator `==` to force string comparison, or using one of `equ`, `neq`, `gtr`, `geq`, `lss`, `leq` for trying to interpret both values as integers and comparing them as such, or, if not possible, comparing them as strings).

Since you have stated the keyword `errorlevel` immediately following the `if` command, a numeric value is expected. The equal-to sign is no longer treated particularly, rather is it just regarded as a standard token delimiter just like a <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, according to [this section](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html#delimiters)<sup>1</sup>, and multiple consecutive delimiters are collapsed into one.

Therefore, your command line `if errorlevel == #` is equivalent to `if errorlevel #`, meaning *if `ErrorLevel` is greater than or equal to `#`*. For that reason, you cannot exchange the two `if` command lines, because an `errorLevel` value of `2` would also fulfil said condition against the value `1`.

---

<sub>1)  Actually, the vertical tabulator (code `0x0B`) and the non-break space (code `0xFF`) are missing in this list.</sub>

Comment: The [example](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001674.htm) you once linked in a (meanwhile deleted) comment is a very bad one, the code presented there contains numerous issues. But a really good resource for batch scripting is [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/)…

Comment: Thanks. It looks like the first poster deleted his answer under which my comment were.